# Neovim scrolloff and virtualedit options randomly changing

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm using LazyVim for my setup and in my `options.lua` I have both `vim.opt.virtualedit = "block"` and `vim.opt.scrolloff = 999`, because that's the way I like it.

But yesterday this strange behavior started happening where in the middle of editing a file, my `virtualedit` and `scrolloff` options get unset.

That is, when I fire up nvim everything is how I want it, but after a while (and I haven't figured out a consistent trigger) my cursor will stop sticking to the center of the screen. And then when I check `set virtualedit?` and `set scrolloff?`, I get `virtualedit=` and `scrolloff=0`, respectively. What the heck?

I'm assuming it's some plugin I have installed that's messing something up, but I'm a relatively new vim user so I'm not sure how to track down what is changing my options. Does anybody have any advice?

I can't find reference to any similar issues online.

Currently, my workaround is a keybinding that calls `:set vim.opt...` to fix it on the fly. But sometimes this still doesn't work (I'll call `:set vim.opt.scrolloff=999` and `scrolloff` won't change). When that happens, I exit nvim and re-open, and everything is back to how I want it.